# XSLT: why the XSLT is not generating output when there are only outer XSL tags

Tags: xslt

My real code is not this, but the problem that i am stating here applies to my real code.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book.child.1>
        <title>charithram</title>
        <author>sarika</author>
    </book.child.1>
    <book.child.2>
        <title>doublebell</title>
        <author>psudarsanan</author>
    </book.child.2>
</books>
```

**XSLT 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="books/*">
            <newbook>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </title>
            </newbook>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**There in no output generated for this XSLT**. I am trying using online tool: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

I could not understand what was wrong, Finally when I modified the XSLT like as written below,

**XSLT 2:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <mytag>
            <xsl:for-each select="books/*">
                <newbook>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                    </title>
                </newbook>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </mytag>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output is generated** in this case:

outputXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mytag>
    <newbook>
        <title>charithram</title>
    </newbook>
    <newbook>
        <title>doublebell</title>
    </newbook>
</mytag>
```

Can you please explain why is this behavior?

Also I don't know how exactly to ask this question, so please edit or let me know if i need to change the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first XSLT will theoretically produce the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newbook>
    <title>charithram</title>
</newbook>
<newbook>
    <title>doublebell</title>
</newbook>
```

But that output is not valid XML, because it has 2 root tags, which is not well-formed XML.

In this situation, you have probably the following choices

- specify a root element like you did in XSLT 2
- change the output from XML to TEXT, but be aware that any XML program will not be able to read the output

Comment: Ok understood, that was not the syntax issue with the XSLT!!. Thank you Thomas, I didn't think of the basic of XML "XML documents must contain one element that is the parent of all other elements. This element is called the root element"!! . Thanks